# How can i reoder lines in a text file based on a pattern?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file that contains batches of 4 lines, the first line of each batch is in the correct position however the next 3 lines are not always in the correct order.

```
name cat
label 4
total 5
value 4

name dog
total 4
label 3
value 6

name cow
value 6
total 1
label 4

name fish
total 3
label 5
value 6
```

I would like each 4 line batch to be in the following format:

```
name cat
value 4
total 5
label 4
```

so the output would be:

```
name cat
value 4
total 5
label 4

name dog
value 6
total 4
label 3

name cow
value 6
total 1
label 4

name fish
value 6
total 3
label 5
```

The file contains thousands of lines in total, so i would like to build a command that can deal with all potential orders of the 3 lines and re-arrange them if not in the correct format.

I am aware i can use awk to search lines that begin with a particular string and them re-arrange them:

```
awk '$1 == "value" { print $3, $4, $1, $2; next; } 1'
```

However i can not figure out how to acheive something similiar that processes over multiple lines.

How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^name/{
  if(name){
    print name ORS array["value"] ORS array["total"] ORS array["label"] ORS
    delete array
  }
  name=$0
  next
}
{
  array[$1]=$0
}
END{
  print name ORS array["value"] ORS array["total"] ORS array["label"]
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding refined solution of above suggested by Kvantour sir.

```
awk -v OFS="\n" '
(!NF) && ("name" in a){
  print a["name"],a["value"],a["total"],a["label"] ORS
  delete a
  next
}
{
  a[$1]=$0
}
END{
  print a["name"],a["value"],a["total"],a["label"]
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: This is a good solution, I would only change the printing not based on `/name/` but based on an empty line. Something like `($NF==0) && ("name" in a) { print array["name"] ORS array["value"] ORS array["total"] ORS array["label"] ORS; delete array; next }` this makes it a bit shorter, and more readable and more generic (assume  `name` is not the first entry)

Comment: In golf, it would look like `awk -v OFS="\n" '(!NF) && ("name" in a) { print a["name"],a["value"],a["total"],a["label"] ORS; delete a;next}{a[$1]=$0}END { print a["name"],a["value"],a["total"],a["label"] }' file`

Answer (score 4):

By setting `RS` to the empty string, each block of text separated by at least one empty line, is considered a single record. From there it's easy to capture each key-value pair and output them in the desired order.

```
BEGIN {RS=""}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) a[$i] = $(i+1)
    print "name", a["name"] ORS \
          "value", a["value"] ORS \
          "total", a["total"] ORS \
          "label", a["label"] ORS
}


$ awk -f a.awk file
name cat
value 4
total 5
label 4

name dog
value 6
total 4
label 3

name cow
value 6
total 1
label 4

name fish
value 6
total 3
label 5
```

Comment: you can remove the `OFS` and just use a `,` instead. The print statement replaces the `,` with `OFS`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"}
     { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { k=substr($i,1,index($i," ")-1); a[k]=$i } }
     { print a["name"],a["value"],a["total"],a["label"] }' file
```

**How does this work?**

Awk knows the concept *records* and *fields*. Files are split in *records* where consecutive records are split by the record separator `RS`. Each record is split in fields, where consecutive fields are split by the field separator `FS`. By default, the record separator `RS` is set to be the <newline> character (`\n`) and thus each record is a line. The record separator has the following definition:

> **`RS`:**
>   The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. **If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input**, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.

So with the file format you give, we can define the records based on `RS=""` and the field separator `FS="\n".

Each record looks simplified as:

```
key1 string1      << field $1
key2 string2      << field $2
key3 string3      << field $3
key4 string4      << field $4
...
keyNF stringNF    << field $NF
```

When awk reads a record, we first parse it by storing all `key-value` pairs in an array `a`. Afterwards, we ask to print the values we find interesting. For this, we need to define the output-field-separators `OFS` and output-record-separator `ORS`.

Comment: Hi Kvantour, if I may ask you,how about this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791392/5866580  IMHO this also looks simpler, whats your opinion?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I commented on it. I believe your solution is indeed simpler. I just like exploiting the natural features of awk.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim you could sort the file in sections using reverse order `sort!`:

```
for i in range(1,line("$"))
  /^name/+1,/^name/+3sort!
endfor
```

Same command issued from the shell:

```
$ ex -s '+for i in range(1,line("$"))|/^name/+1,/^name/+3sort!|endfor' '+%p' '+q!' inputfile
```